# Executing a command in a string in bash

Tags: bash, fastq

I have a string that contains a command that I want to execute in a bash script. How can I do that?
Sorry for so basic question but I am new in bash.
This is my code:

```
echo "What is the path to save the result files?"
read out_path

end_cm1=$"fastqc -o "$out_path$" --noextract -fastq "$files1
```

And I want to execute the instruction that is in the end_cm1 variable.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't have to put that command in a string at all: you can just do this:

```
fastqc -o "$out_path" --noextract -fastq $files1
```

(And I'd recommend putting `$out_path` in quotes here in case the path has a space in it. I've not put `$files1` in quotes because your variable is plural so I assume there's more than one; you should beware spaces in those file names also.)

Second, the answer to the question you asked is `eval`:

```
eval $end_cm1
```

Comment: `eval` is unnecessary here; `x="echo bob"; $x`

Comment: True, that *might* be true here. But you're complicating the issue.

Comment: Avoid `eval` whenever possible, it has a reputation for being a source of weird bugs.  If you must use it, at least double-quote the variable (i.e. `eval "$end_cm1"`).  Loosely speaking, `$end_cm1` does some, but not all, of the normal parsing before executing; `eval $end_cm1` does some parsing and *then parses it again*; `eval "$end_cm1"` parses it exactly once.  For even better alternatives, see Dennis's link.

Answer (score 0):

You just have a slight syntax issue in your string:

```
end_cm1="fastqc -o $out_path --noextract -fastq $files1"
$enc_cm1
```

Having said that, @ams is right about not needing to assign this
to a string in the first place, and about the risks involved
in not quoting `$files1`.

Comment: Specifically, if you have extra quoting levels, or unexpanded variables within `$end_cm1` then you *need* `eval`. If you have no quoting and no variables then `eval` will work the same as without. I prefer to use it just so I know what I'm doing. One should be aware that there is a risk that a user input could have something that gets evaluated (with either option) so don't do it in scripts that might be exploited to hack your system!